# How to get the SHA of head and previous commit of a branch

Tags: github-actions

Is there an easy way by which I can get the current and previous commit's SHA of a branch in GITHUB Action?

I want to use it to check if any files in change in a particular directories

Answer (score 0):

Current SHA commit of the master branch :

```
git rev-parse master
```

Previous commit SHA for the master branch :

```
git rev-parse master~1
```

Comment: Not working getting this error:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'feature/xyz': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.